# Bash: IF and ELSE, comparisons and logical OR gates?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am currently running Archlinux from an external HDD, so I'm trying to make a script in bash that will allow me to change video drivers without having to navigate through configuration files every time I start up from another computer.

I use **nvidia** or **nouveau** at my desktop PCs, but **intel** when I'm at my girlfriend's laptop. Thus, I have been making a bash script with SED that will output the current driver being used to a variable called *$VCARD*, while the one that I want to change to will be the first argument for the script (*$1*, then).

My problem is, I'm trying to make this safe so that I don't accidentally exchange the string that holds nvidia, nouveau or intel to anything that's not these three strings. I thought the best way to make this would be a series of if-else comparisons, like shown below.

```
if [ "$1" = "$VCARD" ]
then
    echo "Already using $VCARD driver."
else
    if [ "$1" = "nouveau" or "intel" or "nvidia" ]  #This is the line that concerns me.
    then
        sed -i -e "7s#\(nouveau\|intel\|nvidia\)#$1#" /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf
        echo "New driver is now $1."
    else
        echo "You don't want to put that string there. (try nouveau, intel or nvidia)"
    fi
fi
```

How do conditionals work when you want to fit in a logical OR gate in the middle?

PD: Yes, I'm using '#'s as separators for the sed command, I hope that's not an eyesore for anyone.

Comment: `||` is for logical or as in many other programming languages

Comment: Using the regular `test` with `[]` won't work with `||` and `&&`. In order to use these, you need `[[` and `]]`. Inside the single square brackets you can use `-a` for AND and `-o` for OR.

Comment: 洋葱头, your example didn't work for me until I added double brackets to that code. Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two possible approaches.

One:
`if [ "$1" = "nouveau" -o "$1" = "intel" -o "$1" = "nvidia" ]`

Two:
`if [[ "$1" = "nouveau" || "$1" = "intel" || "$1" = "nvidia" ]]`

Personally, I would prefer the second. It's closer to what other programming languages employ and it would be understood by a broader spectrum of programmers.

**Edit**: Thanks @Etan Reisner for the helpful comment. This should really be taken into account when deciding which option to choose.

Comment: Both this and mikebridge's solutions worked perfectly. Thanks for pointing out the double brackets issue and for the solution!

Comment: The `-o` solution here is not recommended as it is deprecated and was historically poorly supported. Both the `[[ || ]]` and `[ ] || [ ]` versions are good though. With the single bracket version being more portable and the double bracket version being a bit safer (in terms of quoting needs) and having some different behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Also:

```
if [ "$1" = "nouveau"] || [ "$1" = "intel" ] || ["$1" == "nvidia" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case`:

```
case "$1" in
    "$VCARD")
        echo "Already using $VCARD driver."
        ;;
    nouveau|intel|nvidia)
        sed -i -e "7s#\(nouveau\|intel\|nvidia\)#$1#" /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf
        echo "New driver is now $1."
        ;;
    *)
        echo "You don't want to put that string there. (try nouveau, intel or nvidia)"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: I haven't learned very well how case works yet, but I'll save this example for when I get to see it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This can be simplified further if you put the everything in the `case`, including the first test. Just add another option like this: `$VCARD)
      echo "Already using $VCARD driver."
      ;;`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if [ "$1" = "intel" -o "$1" = "nouveau" -o "$1" = "nvidia" ];
```

Comment: This solution also works, and thank you for submitting it! Though I don't think that last semicolon is necessary :p